# WebApi, no puedo serializar atributos declarados en una clase derivada de Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

No puedo obtener los valores de las propiedades declaradas en BaseException cuando llamo al metodo Get de la API.

```
public class BaseException : Exception
{
    public  string ExType { get; set; }

    public JObject Properties { get; set; }

    public Guid ErrorCodeId { get; set; }

    public BaseException(string message): base(message) { }
}

public class BadRequestException : BaseException
{
    public BadRequestException(string message) : base(message) { }
}

// GET: api/<controller>
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    IHttpActionResult result = null;
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Error description here");
        result = Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new BadRequestException(ex.Message)
        {
            ExType = "Any exception type"//Can't get this value in the output JSON
        }));
    }
    return result;
}
```

La propiedad ExType no se esta mostrando. El resultado es el siguiente:

```
{
  "ClassName": "BadRequestException",
  "Message": "Error description here",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": null,
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

Existe alguna forma para obtener el valor serializado de mis propias propiedades?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
[Serializable()]
    public class BaseException : Exception
    {
        public string ExType { get; set; }

        public JObject Properties { get; set; }

        public Guid ErrorCodeId { get; set; }

        public BaseException(string message) : base(message) { }
    }
```

De forma genérica, sino puedes marcar los tags de cada uno de los atributos.

Aquí te dejo algo de información

[Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: He probado con [Serializable] sin éxito, pero no con [Serializable()]. No sabía que se podía poner eso, es lo mismo o hace alguna diferencia?

Comment: Se supone que no hay diferencias entre ambas. Prueba entonces a marcar también los atributos.